# In Vue (webpack), how can I make certain functions run at compile-time?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

For example, in a component I have a really long constant string. When the component loads, the string goes through a function that edits it in a certain way. So it's always the same. I could've as well written the already-edited version but that would be inconvenient for my project.

So it makes me wonder - is there any way to make that function run at compile-time so when webpack makes a bundle, it will have the edited version only and won't have to run that function every time the component loads, which will be good for performance.

In general, there is a lot of things in my project that I would like to precalculate at compile-time. Say, I write a component with a constant prop:

`<Number n="123">`

Inside that component, I turn `123` into a string `one hundred and twenty three`, so in the end it'll turn into:

`<div> one hundred and twenty three </div>`

Let's imagine that that translation function is actually heavy to calculate. In that case it'd be great if those calculations were made at compile time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same thing and realized that there are better solutions to my problem. It all about how you architect things. As I know there is no simple way to do so in Vue.

Here is a list of ideas you might consider appealing:

1. Despite the fact that the component is mounting multiple times you can **make some code inside of it execute once** during page load.

```js
// BEFORE
export default {
  methods: {
    test() {}
  },
  mounted() {
    const calculated = this.test(); // executes on every component mount
    console.log(calculated);
  }
}

// AFTER
// executed only once during the page load
const calculated = (() => { // code of test function is here });
export default {
  mounted() {
     console.log(calculated);
  }
}
```

2. **Optimize heavy function**. There tons of opportunities to do so. Learn about  complexity of algorithms, `O(n)` and methods of optimization. Moreover, there might be a npm library already optimized for your task.

```js
// Let's assume you need to return list of users that are admins (based on some sort of groups)
// ---
// You have:
// users = [{id: 1, groupId: 1}, {id: 2, groupId: 1}, {id: 3, groupId: 2}]
// groups = [{ id: 1, isAdmin: true }, { id: 2, isAdmin: false }]
// --
// Expected: {id: 1, groupId: 1}, {id: 2, groupId: 1}

// Quick solution: O(N x M)
// If we have 1000 users and 1000 groups it would need 1000x1000 operations which is 1000000
const getAdminUsers = (users, groups) => {
  return users.filter(user => 
    groups.some(group => user.groupId === group.id && group.isAdmin)
  );
};

// Faster solution: O(N + M)
// If we have 1000 users and 1000 groups it would need 1000+1000 operations which is just 2000
const getAdminUsers = (users, groups) => {
  const groupIdToAdminMap = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
     groupIdToAdminMap[i] = groups[i].isAdmin;
  }
  return users.filter(user => groups[user.groupId]);
}
```

3. **Cache**. I know, cache is considered to be one of the hardest things in computer science but something as simple as [memoization](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Memoization) can help a lot. The idea is prevent computations for values which has been computed before

```js
// let's take existing implementation of memoization just to save time
import memoize from 'lodash/memoize'

export default {
  methods: {
    test() {}
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.test = memoize(this.test)
  }
  mounted() {
    const calculated1 = this.test('123'); // triggers expensive calculations
    const calculated2 = this.test('123'); // doesn't trigger expensive calculations
    console.log(calculated1, calculated2);
  }
}
```

4. Supposing none of the options about worked for you, try [babel-plugin-preval](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-preval). It allows to execute some code at transpile time.

```js
// BEFORE transpiling
const greeting = preval`
  const fs = require('fs')
  module.exports = fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('./greeting.txt'), 'utf8')
`;

// AFTER transpiling
const greeting = 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: I am aware of the first three options, they don't work for me. But the fourth option looks very interesting and that's probably exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1850067 good luck with your endeavour